# What is the proper schema for JSON-LD telephone number with extension?

Tags: schema.org, phone-number, json-ld

I'm trying to find the proper schema for telephones with extensions, but I can't find anything related to this problem through Google searches or schema.org.

In HTML, I'm using `,` to trigger the extension on cellphones and Skype, but I've also seen `p` used to "pause" between numbers when dialing. Which is the best route in regards to proper JSON-LD schema?

No extension used:

```json
{
     "@type":           "Organization",
     "telephone":       "+18665554985"
}
```

Style 1 using `p`:

```json
{
     "@type":           "Organization",
     "telephone":       "+18665554985p100"
}
```

Style 2 using `,`:

```json
{
     "@type":           "Organization",
     "telephone":       "+18665554985,100"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`telephone` property](http://schema.org/telephone) has `Text` as expected value. If a specific format should be used, it would be noted in the property’s description, but that’s not the case for `telephone`.¹

So you can use whichever format you want.

**Which format would make sense?** I would go with the same format you display for your users (which would ideally be the recommended format according to a convention/standard relevant for the targeted users). This is the natural choice when using Microdata or RDFa to mark it up, and there is no reason to go a different route for JSON-LD. This would also help in cases where a consumer simply displays your value of the `telephone` property: it will be in the appropriate format for your users.

---

¹ There was some discussion about this in the issue [*Make the telephone property more structured (not just Text)*](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/188). I would expect that the expected range will, at some point, include `URL` values, so that [`tel` URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21855866/1591669) can be used (which of course have a specified format).