# VoiceOver in UIWebView doesn't read phone number properly

Tags: ios, uiwebview, accessibility, voiceover

[I saw a relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774899/voice-over-doesnt-read-phone-number-properly) (from which I'm steeling some text) however the difference here is the phone number is not in my code but in a webpage being loaded in UIWebView.

The UIWebView has a phone number:

**1-1xx-2xx-9565**

Currently VO read it as **"One (pause) One x x (pause) two x x (pause) minus nine thousand five hundred sixty five"**.

VO should read it as **"One (pause) One x x (pause) two x x (pause) nine five six five"**.

If this where in the code, I would apply an accessibility label, however it's not. I can't change the format of the phone number, nor can I prevent the app from loading that page. I can however change the html/css of the webpage and any property of the UIWebViewController.

Is there a way to fix this so VO uses the proper pronunciation?

Comment: use spaces for - and the 9565

Comment: @TejaNandamuri That would be changing the way the phone number is displayed though.

Comment: Only change the accessibility label! That doesn't change the UI!